# How to catch random wild subdomain/domain not register in the vhost

Tags: apache

Currently I'm stopping user direct access to my server via IP with the following conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 123.123.123.123
Redirect permanent / https://google.com
UseCanonicalName Off
</VirtualHost>
```

However, I do setting *.abc.com to my server 123.123.123.123
How can i do the same, redirect those domains are not registered in my vhost serverName?

Comment: Do you need to route these accesses to different virtual hosts depending on the domain?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, the vhost should accessible according to the serverName and Alias, i want to handle those undefined

Comment: If you have a different IP address for each domain I think `<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>` would do but I guess it's a shared IP address so it gets tricker. Perhaps you need [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/vhosts.html).